# What is output of this program and why?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
enum {false, true};
int main()
{
   int i = 1;
   do
   {
      printf("%d\n", i);
      i++;
      if (i < 15){
         continue;
      }
   } while (false);
   return 0;
}
```

Output

> 1

I don't understand why the output is `1`, my assumption is that it because after first iteration it skip all other but how and why ?

Comment: Well the second iteration never happened. You are using `do…while(condition)`. From `do{` to `}while` is your loop body. The number of times this body is executed is the number of iterations. Now coming back to "why?". Your block of code executed once till it reached `}while(false)`. Now it checks the condition inside `while(condition)` which is already `false`. It doesn't go back for second iteration and hence only `1` got printed.

Comment: You may be expecting the `continue` to go back to the "top" of the loop at the `do` statement. But it actually goes to the conditional check in the `while`.

Comment: See the equivalencies [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue). `continue` is commonly taught to jump to the _top_ of the loop, but thinking it skips the rest of the body and goes to the _bottom_ of the loop makes more sense. Notably, `continue` will not skip the loop condition.

Comment: @Amadan -- the C Standard even says as much: ["A continue statement causes a jump to the loop-continuation portion of the smallest enclosing iteration statement; that is, to the end of the loop body"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.2p2)

Comment: `enum {false, true};` what happens with `int a = 5;` and `if (a == true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be expecting the `continue` to go back to the "top" of the loop at the `do` statement. But it actually goes to the end of the loop body. Which in the case of a `do/while` loop is the conditional check in the `while`.

The relevant section from the C standard which explains this:

> A continue statement causes a jump to the loop-continuation portion of the smallest
>   enclosing iteration statement; that is, to the end of the loop body. More precisely, in each of the statements
>
> ```
> while (/* ... */) {
>       /* ... */
>       continue;
>       /* ... */
> contin: ;
> }
>
> do {
>     /* ... */
>     continue;
>    /* ... */
> contin: ;
> } while (/* ... */);
>
> for (/* ... */) {
>     /* ... */
>     continue;
>    /* ... */
> contin: ;
> }
> ```
>
> unless the **continue** statement shown is in an enclosed iteration statement (in which
>   case it is interpreted within that statement), it is equivalent to **goto contin;**

So specifically for your code example the `continue` will result in a jump to `while (false)` on the first iteration which will terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike **for** and **while** loops, which test the loop condition at the top of the loop, the **do...while** loop in C programming checks its condition at the bottom of the loop.

A **do...while** loop is similar to a **while** loop, except the fact that it is ***guaranteed to execute at least one time***.

```
do {
   statement(s);
} while( condition );
```

Notice that the conditional expression appears at the end of the loop, so the statement(s) in the loop executes once before the condition is tested.

If the condition is true, the flow of control jumps back up to do, and the statement(s) in the loop executes again. This process repeats until the given condition becomes false.

And in your case the condition is false that's why the code inside **do...while** loop executed once.